# Android not allocating memory for a app

Tags: android, memory, memory-management

I developed a app that handle a lot of photos, i optimised it quite well, it never use more than 40mb of ram that its pretty aceptable for a app that handle many photos.
My problem is a certain report that i have not been able to respond:

(Its a isolated case but i would really want to know why is this happening)
Target phone: Xperia Z1
I checked and the phone have 500 mb free Ram b4 launching, but the app crashes at the slightes try of loading a image, or doing any action that consume ram (changing a intent or anything at all)
Why is this happening? its only on 1 phone but still make me wonder why android is not allocating memory for my app, i know that the system is working beacause it allocates memory for other apps.

Any light you can shred over this problem would be greatly apretiated!

Sory here you have 2 separated stack traces

```
FolderView: java.lang.OutOfMemoryError
FolderView: android.graphics.BitmapFactory.nativeDecodeStream(Native Method)
FolderView: android.graphics.BitmapFactory.decodeStreamInternal(BitmapFactory.java:620)
FolderView: android.graphics.BitmapFactory.decodeStream(BitmapFactory.java:596)
FolderView: android.graphics.BitmapFactory.decodeFile(BitmapFactory.java:376)
FolderView: app.slidepick.PhotoUtil.getBitmapFromPath(PhotoUtil.java:86)
FolderView: app.slidepick.ImageAdapter.getView(ImageAdapter.java:72)
FolderView: android.widget.AbsListView.obtainView(AbsListView.java:2255)
FolderView: android.widget.GridView.onMeasure(GridView.java:1048)
FolderView: android.view.View.measure(View.java:16628)
FolderView: android.widget.RelativeLayout.measureChildHorizontal(RelativeLayout.java:719)
FolderView: android.widget.RelativeLayout.onMeasure(RelativeLayout.java:455)
FolderView: android.view.View.measure(View.java:16628)
FolderView: android.widget.RelativeLayout.measureChildHorizontal(RelativeLayout.java:719)
FolderView: android.widget.RelativeLayout.onMeasure(RelativeLayout.java:455)
FolderView: android.view.View.measure(View.java:16628)
FolderView: android.view.ViewGroup.measureChildWithMargins(ViewGroup.java:5125)
FolderView: android.widget.FrameLayout.onMeasure(FrameLayout.java:310)
FolderView: android.view.View.measure(View.java:16628)
FolderView: android.view.ViewGroup.measureChildWithMargins(ViewGroup.java:5125)
FolderView: android.widget.LinearLayout.measureChildBeforeLayout(LinearLayout.java:1404)
FolderView: android.widget.LinearLayout.measureVertical(LinearLayout.java:695)
FolderView: android.widget.LinearLayout.onMeasure(LinearLayout.java:588)
FolderView: android.view.View.measure(View.java:16628)
FolderView: android.view.ViewGroup.measureChildWithMargins(ViewGroup.java:5125)
FolderView: android.widget.FrameLayout.onMeasure(FrameLayout.java:310)
FolderView: com.android.internal.policy.impl.PhoneWindow$DecorView.onMeasure(PhoneWindow.java:2298)
FolderView: android.view.View.measure(View.java:16628)
FolderView: android.view.ViewRootImpl.performMeasure(ViewRootImpl.java:1916)
FolderView: android.view.ViewRootImpl.measureHierarchy(ViewRootImpl.java:1113)
FolderView: android.view.ViewRootImpl.performTraversals(ViewRootImpl.java:1295)
FolderView: android.view.ViewRootImpl.doTraversal(ViewRootImpl.java:1000)
FolderView: android.view.ViewRootImpl$TraversalRunnable.run(ViewRootImpl.java:5622)
FolderView: android.view.Choreographer$CallbackRecord.run(Choreographer.java:761)
FolderView: android.view.Choreographer.doCallbacks(Choreographer.java:574)
FolderView: android.view.Choreographer.doFrame(Choreographer.java:544)
FolderView: android.view.Choreographer$FrameDisplayEventReceiver.run(Choreographer.java:747)
FolderView: android.os.Handler.handleCallback(Handler.java:733)
FolderView: android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:95)
FolderView: android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:212)
FolderView: android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:5135)
FolderView: java.lang.reflect.Method.invokeNative(Native Method)
FolderView: java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:515)
FolderView: com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:877)
FolderView: com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:693)
FolderView: dalvik.system.NativeStart.main(Native Method)


TakePhoto: java.lang.OutOfMemoryError
TakePhoto: android.graphics.Bitmap.nativeCreate(Native Method)
TakePhoto: android.graphics.Bitmap.createBitmap(Bitmap.java:810)
TakePhoto: android.graphics.Bitmap.createBitmap(Bitmap.java:787)
TakePhoto: android.graphics.Bitmap.createBitmap(Bitmap.java:719)
TakePhoto: app.slidepick.TakePhoto.RotateBitmap(TakePhoto.java:349)
TakePhoto: app.slidepick.TakePhoto$4.onPictureTaken(TakePhoto.java:305)
TakePhoto: android.hardware.Camera$EventHandler.handleMessage(Camera.java:941)
TakePhoto: android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:102)
TakePhoto: android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:212)
TakePhoto: android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:5135)
TakePhoto: java.lang.reflect.Method.invokeNative(Native Method)
TakePhoto: java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:515)
TakePhoto: com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:877)
TakePhoto: com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:693)
TakePhoto: dalvik.system.NativeStart.main(Native Method)
```

Comment: There is no way we can help you without more information. Can you please post the stacktrace? You are probably getting an OOM.

Comment: "it never use more than 40mb of ram that its pretty aceptable for a app that handle many photos" -- it is also larger than your available heap on many Android devices. "Why is this happening?" -- use LogCat to see where and why you are crashing. "why android is not allocating memory for my app" -- you may have reached your heap limit. Your Java code cannot allocate arbitrary amounts of memory. Call `getMemoryClass()` on `ActivityManager` to determine your heap size limit.

Comment: If you are having an `OutOfMemoryError`, you have either hit your heap limit or are suffering from [memory fragmentation due to the Dalvik VM garbage collector](http://commonsware.com/blog/2014/06/16/art-garbage-collection.html).

Comment: The Mexican: Off course i am getting a OOM, my question is why i am getting it in a phone that have so much ram available, while on my worst test phone that have less than 1/5 of the available ram it dont crash and work really smooth?
@CommonsWare we dont support phones that old, and a Xperia Z1 is way better than any of the test phones i am using. btw its 40mb in stress mode it almost never go that far.

Comment: Well, I do not know for a fact, I am going to guess here. I am assuming that the phone with the least memory is of a lower screen density than the phone with more RAM. This means that the amount of Bitmap memory needed by the lower resolution device is within the bounds for that device. The phone with more RAM and more resolution has to process more data for each picture (more pixels to process) an hence it runs out of memory. I do not think it is a RAM issue, I its a Bitmap memory issue, but I might be wrong.

Comment: @TheMexican no, i never load the full photo, i only load the size i need with justdecodebounds command, and i tried it with really heavy photos on a really crappy phone, thats why i am so shocked a phone that good run out of memory, its hard to believe that its a app problem since we tested the app in more than 40 phones already and only 1 of those have the problem, but the phone seems fine aswell XD

Comment: How big is the image?

Comment: @323go i tried with really heavy ones 30mb without crashing, yet he crash with the default camara taken photo Xperia Z1 (not more than 10mb)